# Name of USB Adapter without Extension to Prevent Pins Tearing

Tags: usb, desktop-computer

I am continuously changing USB Cables from the back of my computer, and accidentally pulled one of the USB pins on back of Dell Desktop.

I am looking for a USB adapter,  USB-A Male to USB-A Female, without any extension wires. I would plug this USB into desktop, as a protector, to prevent actual Desktop USB wear/tear.

What is the name of this, similar to picture below, without any wire extension?

[image]

Note: I want to keep USB A to USB A. No type change to USB C.

Comment: extension cable gives me products with long wires, I just want a USB male to USB female adapter, no long wires

Comment: hi @Peregrino69 most of the products I found are changing the adapter types from USB C to A,  I want to KEEP the original type, I think its a different name not sure

Comment: no, I want to keep USB A to USB A,  no type change @Peregrino69

Comment: Fixed the question for you. I doubt those exist, as it'd be a really niche market. I can't from the top of my head think of any practical use for them. EDIT I stand corrected, they do: https://www.l-com.com/usb-usb-30-adapter-type-a-male-to-type-a-female. So you're looking for USB-A Male to USB-A Female adapter.

Comment: @mattsmith5 then start searching for "usb extension" with qualifiers like "short" or "10cm"

Comment: I found a few just by googling `usb-a male to usb-a female adapter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for a "socket saver", aka USB Type A Male to A Female Adapter.  These are sometimes described as laptop adapters.
Available in straight (opposing) or a variety of right-angle versions.

[image]

Some of these USB 2.x products are getting difficult to find as manufacturers seem to be progressing to USB 3.0 products.

[image]